# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal class access:

Tags: android, android-volley, proguard

Getting error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                          Process: com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing, PID: 17274
>                                                                                          java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal class access:
>   'com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices' attempting to
>   access 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzccb' (declaration of
>   'com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices' appears in
>   /data/app/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes29.dex)
>                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                              at
>   com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing.activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:142)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

getting error in this line

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
```

whenever i tried to open my app its force closing with above error,actually i want to send user location to server so i need to access that location from device.

Comment: please sombody help me....

Comment: Nikhil Patil did you found any solution?